# Can there be a scenario where the use of an IED against an enemy is legally justifiable? (It's for a book, I swear...)

Tags: military, laws-of-war

Before I go any further, let me be clear that **this is for a work of fiction**.

Doing some research for a story where a military protagonist becomes trapped behind enemy lines, with a plan to have her hold out until rescue against superior forces by adopting asymmetric warfare tactics, including the use of improvised explosive devices. This is an urban environment, but it's a situation where most of the civilians formerly in the area are already gone (either dead, fled, or captured), and she's actively trying to keep the enemy away from a pocket of survivors.

Under standard Western rules of war, is it legal for her to use [IEDs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improvised_explosive_device) in this context? [I did a little research already](http://www.defenseone.com/ideas/2013/09/are-ieds-ever-ethical-weapon-battlefield/70892/) but that article mostly just deals with IEDs being used partially or fully for ideological reasons with no care to collateral damage (and often deliberately targeting civilians).

Comment: What's an IED? I'm really confused...

Comment: @Zizouz212: "Improvised Explosive Device", i.e. a homemade bomb.

Comment: Actually I'm confused why the OP thought it necessary to put an "It's for a book" disclaimer *in the title*?  Those are funny when the question is of the "How do I get away with murder?" or "How do I construct an IED out of household supplies?" sort.  But am I missing the moral hazard in answering a question like this?  Some combatant in some theater of war is considering the *legality* of using an IED, and the answers provided here will be abused to ... what?  Ignore some ROE?  Like someone is going to tell a court martial or war crimes tribunal, "But I read on Law.SE it's OK!"

Comment: @feetwet : I was just trying to be careful I didn't inadvertently offend anyone, TBH.

Comment: Like the sticky bomb they made in Saving Private Ryan? If Tom Hanks does it, I'm sure it's legit.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that an explosive device is *improvised* is irrelevant to any law of war with which I am familiar.

"Legal in war" is more a matter of deciding [which treaty, convention, or custom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_war) you care to respect.

Answer (score 1):

An IED is simply a land mine that is home made rather than mass produced in a factory. Land mines are illegal under the [Ottawa Treaty](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottawa_Treaty) which currently has 165 parties: if used by or against members of the forces of those countries the user would be liable to prosecution as a war criminal.

Comment: Anti-personnel mines, specifically.

Comment: That treaty appears to only be about anti-personnel automatically triggered mines. IEDs can also be remotely triggered or anti-vehicle.